# Stop All Running Workflows on DEV Enviroment

Tags: 2007, workflow, email

We have created a DEV environment by attaching the content DBs from the live environment to the DEV environment. We faced an issue where users were receiving workflow task notification emails for tasks they had already completed and later figured that these were coming from the DEV environment and so had to disable outgoing emails on DEV. We now want to restore the email functionality on DEV but do now want the users to be spammed. What are the options for cancelling all running workflows on the DEV environment?